# Why my code works without chroot function, but fail with chroot function?

Tags: c++, chroot, execl

I try to make my code work under `chroot('/root/test1')`, but it doesn't work correctly.

But when I delete `chroot('/root/test1')`, and modify `execl("/test2", "test2", NULL)` to `execl("/root/test1/test2", "test2", NULL)`, it will work very well as expected. Why is that?

In addition, I would like to ask that if I set `fp` redirect to `stdin`, and then use `execl` function to work another program, the child program will get input at `fp` whether or not?

The file in '/root/test1/':

```
test2
test2.cpp
test3
test3.cpp
```

The value return by execl funtion is -1 and errno is 2.

**test3.cpp**

```cpp
int main() {
    FILE *fp;
    errno = 0;
    fp = fopen("log.txt", "r");
    dup2(fileno(fp), fileno(stdin));
    cout << chdir("/root/test1") << endl;
    cout << chroot("/root/test1") << endl;

    DIR *dir = opendir("/");
    dirent *list;
    while ((list = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        cout << list -> d_name << "  ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    closedir(dir);
    errno = 0;
    cout << execl("/test2", "test2", NULL) << endl;
    cout << errno << endl;
    cout << strerror(errno) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**test2.cpp**

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int a,b;
    cin >> a;
    scanf("%d",&b);
    cout << a+b << endl;
    printf("%d",a+b);
    return 0;
}
```

**log.txt**

```
111 222
```

**output***

```
0
0
.  test3.cpp  test3  ..  test2  test2.cpp  log.txt
-1
2
No such file or directory
```

Comment: What is in `test2`? Is it a executable? A shell script? Does it link with shared libraries? What is the output of `ldd test2` ? Does those shared libraries are copied to `/root/test1`?

Comment: Have you checked what each of your system calls return? There's no failure anywhere?

Comment: Only the root user is allowed to `chroot`. Are you running as root?

Comment: Also note that in Linux, `2` is the error `ENOENT` meaning that `execl` can't find the program. Use e.g. `strerror(errno)` to print a string with a short explanation of the error.

Comment: @Steve You need to check after every call. Some functions leave `errno` untouched on success, and some reset it to a non-error state.

Comment: For almost all functions, the state of `errno` is *undefined* after the call, unless there's an error. You need to check what the functions actually *return* to see if they fail or succeed. Only if a function failed you should check the value of `errno`, and you should get (and possibly store in a temporary variable) as soon as possible (before another function *might* change it).

Comment: What does `chroot` ***return***? You need to check that it succeeds. What happens if it fails? Right now, with the code you show, you don't check for that. You need to do something like `if (chroot(...) == -1) { perror("chroot"); return 1; }`

Comment: The error is likely due to missing libraries in the chrooted directory.

Comment: @Ian Abbott So how to solve it?

Comment: One way is to make test2 do the chroot itself (using argv arguments to tell it where to chroot to), at which point it should have already loaded its libraries.

Comment: Thanks. Lack of libraries is right. I try to copy /usr /lib /lib64 and /bin/bash to /root/test1, and it can works perfectly! @Ian Abbott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy /usr /lib /lib64 and /bin/bash to /root/test1